# Blank text magnifier in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, ios6, ios7

I'm working on an iOS 6 app that's needs to be compatible with iOS 7. For some strange reason whenever I deploy the app on an iOS 7 device, if I try to magnify text, the magnifier is blank.

Here's a screenshot of the issue

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem here. If you find a solution, please share. This works fine in the simulator but not on the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there are multiple UIWindows in the .xib. At least that was the problem for me. I was using a UIWindow for VGA output. As soon as I deleted the window from the .xib my cursor worked. I then recreated the UIWindow in code.